# Javascript: Use function as variable

Tags: javascript, variables

Is there a way to use a variable name which has a function assigned to it, for example, to get the actual width of an element?

`var xvar = function(){ return $('#y').width()}`

And use it as

`console.log(xvar);`

Instead of

`console.log(xvar());`

Comment: You can't call a function without calling a function, in general, though you might want to look at using property getter functions (in newer JavaScript interpreters only). *edit* see @pimvdb's answer :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not with variables, but it is possible with properties on objects. It's called a getter.

```
var obj = {
  get xvar() { return $('#y').width(); }
};
```

Then you can use:

```
obj.xvar;  // will run the above function
```

(Theoretically, a way to use a variable getter is when an object's properties reflect the variables. For example, the `window` object.)

Comment: +1. If I'm not wrong, it's not fully cross browser supported.

Comment: Is that ES5/6? I've never heard of this. It's awesome though.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine. goggle javascript getter.

Comment: @gdororn: Very true, good point. @ Florian Magazine: [ES5 specs are here](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5).

Comment: @gdoron not much help, Google is crowded with stuff like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10915948/851498). Is this syntax some `defineProperty` sugarized?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine. You should learn how to google things about javascript. you add an MDN prefix... [Example](https://www.google.co.il/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+getter+mdn)

Comment: Damn, this is nice, BUT IE8... grrr :)

Comment: Yeah, IE8 fail definitely makes it non-cross-browser viable, IMO. DOM objects only. Which is weird because old FF was only non-DOM objects.

Comment: I don't know much of IE's behaviour, but perhaps `var obj = document.createElement("a")` instead of `var obj = {}` may then work. You'd then use `Object.defineProperty`. A bit hacky, but oh well :)

Comment: `defineProperty` is *shimmable* on IE8, not IE7. It's not native though, and it's only shimmable on DOM elements. IE's still a PITA.

Comment: Also, please be wary of using getters and setters that have side effects. That will lead to some very confusing code.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your function returns `String` or `Number` this could be an  alternative for non-ES5 environments:

```
var xvar = new function(id){ 
              this.toString = 
              this.valueOf = function(){
                   return $(id).width()};
           }('#y');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I not mistake it will work because `xvar` will store reference to result of immediately-invoked function:

```
var xvar = (function() { return $('#y').width(); })();
console.log(xvar);
```

But after it you can't use `xvar()` version.

Comment: This is basically equivalent to `var xvar = $('#y').width();`. It won't run the function on access.

Comment: Yeah, that just assigns the return value in the first place. You wouldn't get an updated version of width with that.