# javascript use a function as a variable (getter)

Tags: javascript, getter

I'm just trying to get a "getter" in javascript in this way

```
var Product = function(){
  var self = this; 
  var _id = function() { 
    return self.styleCode + '-' + self.materialCode + '-' + self.colourCode; 
  }
  self.materialCode = ''
  self.colourCode = ''
  ..
  self.id = _id()
}
..
var obj = new Product();
//.. initialize properies
obj.id // = "--"
```

But it seems doesn't call the function every time as I believed.
I tried to use this [Javascript: Use function as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915926/javascript-use-function-as-variable) something like this

```
var Product = function(){
  var self = this; 
  self.materialCode = ''
  self.colourCode = ''
  ..
  get self.id() { return self.materialCode + '-' + self.colourCode; }
}
```

but I get an exception on the get keyword.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: `get self.id() { ... }` --- what does this code mean?

Comment: `get` is not cross-browser. This reserved word don't run in all browsers. I try to provide you another solution, I'm searching for it

Comment: @zerkms see the link in the post

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it works in all modern browsers

Comment: If you [look more closely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), this syntax is used in an object initializer; I don't know if it will work in a function declaration. Also, the browser has to support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the `id` property on `self`, with `Object.defineProperty`, like this

```
Object.defineProperty(self, 'id', {
    get: function () {
      return self.materialCode + '-' + self.colourCode;
    }
});
```

You can see [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Defining_a_getter_on_existing_objects_using_defineProperty) from MDN, for reference.

Comment: Thanks this works, is there any browsers compatibility issue ?

Comment: @DevT: Yes, it's not supported IE8 and below. See MDN-article.

Comment: @Mouser this isn't good.. so this is the better way to do a getter but it isn't supported on IE8 and below.

Comment: @DevT, yep, modern websites should't support those older browsers anymore. Windows 10 is coming. Time to wave goodbye to all IE browsers before IE10. However get and set is supported on DOM nodes in IE8.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Object.defineProperty` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```js
var Product = function(){
  var self = this; 
  self.materialCode = ''
  self.colourCode = ''

  Object.defineProperty(self, "id", {
        //printing the full code here
        get : function(){return self.materialCode + '-' + self.colourCode;},
        set : function(value){ null },
        enumerable : false,
        configurable : false
        //this is the default set up for Object.defineProperty when using getters and setters,
        //those two other properties default to false.
  });
}

var obj = new Product();
obj.materialCode = 124;
obj.colourCode = 5783;
alert(obj.id);
```

Just invoke with `obj.id`.

You can set the `set` and `get` function. And use it as a normal property declaration. I *urge* you to read the article on *MDN* to learn more about the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Is another way

```
var xvar = new function(id){ 
    this.toString = this.valueOf = function() {
         return $(id).width();
    };
}('#y');
```

Answer (score 0):

getter and setters are made in different way

with this code

```
self.id = _id();
```

you are storing in self.id return value of _id() called in constructor

with this code

```
get self.id()
```

you are declaring a getter with a parameter (correct way `get id()`)

here you can find usefull information about getter/setter and don't forget firefox **GETTER** and **SETTER**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

keep warning! this code do not work in non-firefox browsers!